# Finding middle number in dynamic array C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the middle number in my dynamic array. A user enters three numbers and the program then sorts it from smallest to biggest. It works fine until I enter the numbers 10,20,30 it outputs 10,10,30 and when I input 30,20,10 it outputs 10,30,30.

Here is part of my code.
Thanks

```
cout << "Enter 3 values and I will sort them from lowest to highest." << endl;

for (index = 0; index < 3; index++)
{
    cin >> number[index];

    while (cin.fail())//Check that values entered are the correct type.
    {
        cout << "You did not enter a number" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a new number." << endl;
        cin.clear();//Clears the input if user input non-integer value.
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');//Ignores up to 1000 characters or up to new line.

        cin >> number[index];
    }//end while
}//end for

cout << "You have entered the values" << endl;
for (index = 0; index < 3; index++)
{
    cout << number[index] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}//end for

small = number[0];
mid = number[0];
high = number[0];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)//Goes through the array to determine order of values.
{
    if (small > number[i])
    {
        small = number[i];
    }
    else if (high < number[i])
    {
        high = number[i];
    }
    else if (high > mid && mid > small)
    {
        mid = number[i];
    }

}

cout << "Here is the new order of your numbers." << endl;
cout << small << endl;
cout << mid << endl;
cout << high << endl;
```

Comment: You need to show us how you declare number

Comment: You should use a debugger to step through your code to find out why the output differs from what you expect.

Comment: The question does not demonstrate much research. Walk through your loop with a piece of paper to see why each of the variables end up with the values that they have.

Comment: to solve this yourself, add a print out of the values in each if statement e.g. cout << "mid: " << mid << endl;

Comment: your if condition, work better from biggest to smallest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in the block below is flawed

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (small > number[i])
    {
        small = number[i];
    }
    else if (high < number[i])
    {
        high = number[i];
    }
    else if (high > mid && mid > small)
    {
        mid = number[i];
    }
```

}

since `small`, `med`, and `high` are not ordered to start with. You can use `std::sort`, as suggested in the answer by @kmac. If you want to code this yourself, try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   if (small > number[i])
   {
      small = number[i];
   }

   if (high < number[i])
   {
      high = number[i];
   }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   if ( number[i] > small && number[i] < high )
   {
      mid = number[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: I thought std::sort had lower time complexity than this?

Comment: For an array of size 3, it doesn't make much difference which method is used. Regardless, for a large array, the time complexity of `std::sort` is `O(N*log(N))` while this approach will need `O(N)` time.

Comment: Using the additional for loop fixed it. Thanks for the help, spent hours trying to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, you can use `std::sort` from `<algorithm>`, although it will modify your array (make a copy if you want to keep the original input).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int nums[] = {5, 1, 7};
    unsigned int num_size = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]);

    std::sort(nums, nums+num_size);

    std::cout << "Here is the order of your numbers:" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<num_size; ++i)
        std::cout << nums[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Here is the order of your numbers:
1
5
7
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your third if-case when you check for 'mid', that will never be true because you assume high is 30 but you have not checked number[2]=='30' at that point.

Instead write something like this

```
// first find max,min
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
  if (number[i] < small)
  {
    small = number[i];
  }
  if (number[i] > high) 
  {
    high = number[i];
  }
}
// then find mid
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
  if (number[i] > small && number[i] < high)
  {
    mid = number[i];
  }
}
```